# CSRF error on Mobile Safari

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, csrf

I currently have CSRF enabled on all my POST Form. This works fine on all browsers except on Mobile Safari. Mobile Safari ALWAYS return a 419 HTTP error and this is a real problem since these users cannot register on my website. I am using the Laravel framework.

What can I do to prevent these errors on mobile Safari?

I am using the CSRF in my ajax call like so:

```
headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': this.$csrfToken.attr('content')},
```

with the token being set by laravel in the meta tags:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: How are you passing the CSRF token, are you depending on Javascript to do it or are you manually including the CSRF token in your form?

Comment: Using the headers parameters in my ajax call like so:

headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': this.$csrfToken.attr('content')},

with the meta set by laravel:

<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Comment: You need to determine if the issue is with including the header in the request, or if the issue is with obtaining the token from the meta tag. You could output the the CSRF token via Javascript, or in the error handler you could log all the headers when it's a CSRF error. I expect the issue is that your Javascript is broken in mobile Safari for some reason.